# Html page printable - Dynamic table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a printable page written in html. In this page I have a simple table, and a footer below.
This table must be "dynamic" if the number the lines is for example greater than 20 (for example) it must put the sequence of the rows in another page. And the footer also must be placed at the bottom of the second page.

All this is done, but the problem is that the footer has a `background-color: white;` suvol (like Elevation) the last line of the table (that of the first page for example) and thus we see more the first lines of the table of the first page

Is there a solution for not letting the array exceeded a certain length value in an A4 size page ?

The code that groups the page:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;*/
  color: black;
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204); 
}
  #page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
}
```

The footer code that flies over the table :

```
    footer {
      width: 21cm;
      position: fixed;
      background-color: transparent;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    footer p:nth-child(1) {
      height: 10px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #52a2ca;
      text-align: center;
    }

    footer p:nth-child(1) span {
      font-size: 8pt;
      background-color: white;
      padding-left: 2%;
    }

footer p:nth-child(2) {
  float: right;
}
```

The code of the table is simple nothing special.

Screenshot:

[image: http://imgur.com/Neh4qK6]

Comment: Have i understood correctly that the footer covers the bottom part of the table if it exceeds a number of rows, and you want to split it in two tables before that happens? Otherwise please rephrase your question: expecaly "see more the first lines" and "suvol (like Elevation) the last" where unclear to me.

Comment: @SamuelKirschner Yes, that's it. Here is a screenshot :
http://imgur.com/Neh4qK6

Comment: Do you need a css solution. As you are mentioning an array, it sounds like you are generating the table with a programm.

Comment: @SamuelKirschner Yes, but at the moment I am looking for a CSS solution

Comment: Have you tried something like `tr:nth-child(20n+0) {page-break-after: always;}`?